# Why is my pointer not null after free?

Tags: c, free

```
void getFree(void *ptr)
{
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        free(ptr);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
char *a;
a=malloc(10);
getFree(a);
if(a==NULL)
    printf("it is null");
else
    printf("not null");
}
```

**Why is the output of this program not NULL?**

Comment: The conditional before `free` is not necessary. It's perfectly OK to call `free(0)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because the pointer is copied *by value* to your function.  You are assigning `NULL` to the local copy of the variable (`ptr`).  This does not assign it to the original copy.

The memory will still be freed, so you can no longer safely access it, but your original pointer will not be `NULL`.

This the same as if you were passing an `int` to a function instead.  You wouldn't expect the original `int` to be edited by that function, unless you were passing a pointer to it.

```
void setInt(int someValue) {
    someValue = 5;
}

int main() {
    int someOtherValue = 7;
    setInt(someOtherValue);
    printf("%i\n", someOtherValue); // You'd expect this to print 7, not 5...
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to null the original pointer, you'll have to pass a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void getFree(void** ptr) {
    /* Note we are dereferencing the outer pointer,
    so we're directly editing the original pointer */

    if (*ptr != NULL) {
        /* The C standard guarantees that free() safely handles NULL,
           but I'm leaving the NULL check to make the example more clear.
           Remove the "if" check above, in your own code */
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }

    return;
}

int main() {
    char *a;
    a = malloc(10);

    getFree(&a); /* Pass a pointer-to-pointer */

    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("it is null");
    } else {
        printf("not null");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the `getFree()` function takes a copy of the pointer. `ptr` and `c` are both pointers, but they are different variables. It's the same reason why this function will output "6":

```
void Magic(int x)
{
    x = 1;
}

void main()
{
    int a = 6;
    Magic(a);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are passing pointer `a` by value, so it is not modified by function. It's only a copy of pointer modified within function, the original variable value is not affected.

Update:

If you wanted to make your life easier by replacing freeing + nulling a variable with a single line of code, you need either a macro:

```
#define MYFREE(x) free(x); x = NULL;
```

or a function with pointer to pointer argument:

```
void myfree(void** pp) { free(*pp); *pp = NULL; }
```

Comment: `getFree` function has no access to original variable, it's only modifying a copy of `a` on stack.

Comment: References do not exist in C.

Comment: +1 for understanding why i am doing this..!! i will use now ur macro

Comment: @Corbin: Thanks for correction, I suspected this so two other options still apply.

Comment: As mentioned above by Corbin, it is not. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Mostly personal preference (though also because macro misuse can cause hard to find errors and macros can be easy to misuse), but I would probably use an inline function instead of a macro.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are stored as integers somewhere in memory.

When you do `a = malloc(10);`, `a` has some value, say 0x1.

When you call `getFree(a);`, the function copies `a` into `void *ptr`.

Now `a=0x1` and `ptr=0x1`.

When you do `ptr=NULL`, only `ptr` is changed to NULL, but `a` is still 0x1..

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the pointer By value.. (By default C passes the argument by value) which means you are updating the copy only ..not the real location..for that you might need to use pointer to pointer in C

```
void getFree(void **ptr)
{

    if(*ptr != NULL)
    {
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not fit to the question. Mr.32 is not just calling `free`.

Comment: I think, I miss read it.. sorry..I made the correction please check it :D

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered but if it helps, I can explain it graphically.

[You are doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZXs2.png) --> the pointer is copied by value to your function so it points to the array

[but instead you want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8CeH.png) -->point to the original pointer

As Merlyn Morgan-Graham already said, the way to solve it is to add operators * and &.