# Seting null value to x(in the language implementation) in free(x)

Tags: c, pointers, free

It is generally advised to assign NULL to a freed up pointer as otherwise it may lead to dangling pointer. I want to know if there is any case where not assigning NULL has some use?

If not, why is it not implemented in the call to 'free()' itself? I understand that the pointer is passed by value and thus cannot be modified. Could the function free() have been be implemented to accept pointer to a pointer(i.e reference to the pointer) where the pointer(not pointer to pointer) points to NULL in the end?

I am asking this since we have to always keep in mind about assigning NULL to pointer after freeing which is a very commonly called function(I am assuming).

Comment: Setting it to `NULL` (which is just `0`, by the way) takes CPU time. Sometimes it's simply not necessary (because you're not using the pointer anymore), so why force the program to waste a few split nanoseconds there?

Comment: It's c. The main aim is to go fast. I often free a pointer only to malloc a bigger chunk of memory to the same variable immediatley

Comment: if you don't like how `free()` and `delete` work, why not write a function or macro which extends it's functionality? `#define free2(x) (free(x); x=NULL;)`

Comment: It's not in `C++` because it wasn't in `C`, it wasn't in `C` because references were not possible and `ptr = NULL` has a runtime cost. Effectively `free` would have to take a double ptr or be implemented as a macro in `C`.

Comment: Another option taken by Objective C with Zombies enabled is to keep the pointer and memory, but move it to another list and mark it as "released". When a program touches the memory associated with the "released" pointer then diagnostics flag the access and alert the programmer.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and different perspectives. I am satisfied with them :D

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not for the code but us. cause ***free*** doesn't set the pointer to NULL, as if may be needed in some low level situation for some, and  more generally the approach of C/C++ is to do things manually by programmer as if they may need specific requirements and this is one the being so **pro** of **C/C++**.

Anyway, by setting the pointer to NULL , now if it's happened to be used later in code now we can check if it's NULL or not, and this prevent from dangling and using unallocated memory pointers.

[Setting variable to NULL after free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025589/setting-variable-to-null-after-free)

[Why is my pointer not null after free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608714/why-is-my-pointer-not-null-after-free?rq=1)

https://www.quora.com/Why-should-we-assign-NULL-to-the-elements-pointer-after-freeing-them

https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-c-pointer-mistakes/

https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152148

Comment: "and more generally the approach of C/C++ is to do things manually by programmer" not really so much in modern C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had been through the first 3 links.