# Data still available after using free function

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list

I have some problem. I need to write function (ft_list_clear), that delete all elements from selected element in linked list. The function is work correctly: after using this function, data not in the list, but still available in other data. Let me show.

My main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hd.h"
#include "ft.c"



t_list  *ft_create_elem(void *data)
t_list  *ft_list_push_params(int arc, char **arv);
void    ft_list_clear(t_list **head);

void print_pointer(void *data)
{
  printf("%s ", *&data);
}

void print_linked_list(t_list *head)
{
  t_list *node = head;

  while (node)
  {
    print_pointer(node->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

head1 = ft_list_push_params(argc, argv);
print_linked_list(head1);

void *link1 = head1->data;
void *link2 = head1->next->data;
void *link3 = head1->next->next->data;
void *link4 = head1->next->next->next->data;
print_pointer(link1);
print_pointer(link2);
print_pointer(link3);
print_pointer(link4);
printf("\n");
ft_list_clear(&head1);
printf("cleared\n");
print_pointer(link1);
print_pointer(link2);
print_pointer(link3);
print_pointer(link4);
printf("\n");
print_linked_list(head1);

return 0;
}
```

My ft.c:

```
#include "hd.h"

t_list  *ft_create_elem(void *data)
{
    t_list *node;

    if (!(node = malloc(sizeof(t_list))))
        return (0);
    node->data = data;
    node->next = 0;
    return (node);
}

void    ft_list_push_front(t_list **head, void *data)
{
    t_list *node;
    if (!(*head))
        *head = ft_create_elem(data);
    else
    {
        node = ft_create_elem(data);
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }
}

t_list  *ft_list_push_params(int ac, char **av)
{
    t_list *head;
    int i;

    i = 1;
    head = 0;
    while (i < ac)
    {
        ft_list_push_front(&head,av[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (head);
}

void    ft_list_clear(t_list **begin_list)
{   
    if (*begin_list && (*begin_list)->next)
        ft_list_clear(&(*begin_list)->next);
    free(*begin_list);
    *begin_list = 0;
}
```

And header:

```
#ifndef FT_LIST_H

# define FT_LIST_H

typedef struct      s_list
{
    struct s_list   *next;
    void            *data;
}                   t_list;

#endif
```

code to run:

```
gcc main.c | ./a.out 111 222 333 444 | cat -e
```

Int this case i have followed output:

```
444 333 222 111 $
cleared$
444 333 222 111 $
$
```

So, I've got a question: why string with "444 333..." is printed second time. I have free this memory. Of not? Why data at *linkN still available?

Added::
**Lundin, geniously. I think that may be marked as answer.** But how can i check that without printing? How someone can exam me in this question? My task - make "free" function. What if i say (head = 0)? It is not solution, but same result in my mind. 
**Thanks to Andrew Henle for explanations.**

Comment: where do you malloc memory for each node ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my pointer not null after free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608714/why-is-my-pointer-not-null-after-free)

Comment: @Yunnosch he calls free() but he calls no alloc().

Comment: i just forgot add ft_create_elem() function at ft.c. Added but problem still.

Comment: If your parking ticket expires, why isn't the car instantly towed away from the parking lot? Because nobody is _obliged_ to do that. When you return to the parking lot your car might still be there, even though it isn't allowed to be. Or it might have been towed away and some other car is there, causing you to trigger its burglar alarm when you try to access it. It is not defined what will happen. What it all boils down to is that RAM memory has no magic "deleted" state.

Comment: Yunnosch, no, as I understand. I had free the memory at **head, so when i call print_linked_list(head) it is output is empty.

Comment: This is explicitly listed as [undefined behavoir in the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2).  You're using the pointer after calling `free()`: "The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used"  It might appear to work. This time.  It might blow up and fail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lundin and Andrew Henle give comprehensive answers in comments. Thanks for that, i've get an answer. Theirs answers may be marked as solutions:

> If your parking ticket expires, why isn't the car instantly towed away
>   from the parking lot? Because nobody is obliged to do that. When you
>   return to the parking lot your car might still be there, even though
>   it isn't allowed to be. Or it might have been towed away and some
>   other car is there, causing you to trigger its burglar alarm when you
>   try to access it. It is not defined what will happen. What it all
>   boils down to is that RAM memory has no magic "deleted" state. –
>   **Lundin**
>
> This is explicitly listed as [undefined behavoir in the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2).
>   You're using the pointer after calling free(): "The value of a pointer
>   that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc
>   function is used" It might appear to work. This time. It might blow up
>   and fail. – **Andrew Henle**